# Maven recommends not using test-jars, yet I would end up with a cyclic dependency

Tags: java, maven, structure, project-structure

I have 2 modules in the following structure

- lib

  - src/main/java

    - MyInterface
  - src/test/java

    - MyMockObject implements MyInterface
    - MyTest1 - uses MyMockObject
- main dependsOn: -lib test-jar scope: test & -lib

  - src/test/java

    - MyTest2 - uses MyMockObject

Currently this was fine as my main module would add a dependency on the lib's test-jar module, however as seen here https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/examples/create-test-jar.html It is recommended to instead create a -test module and expose that rather than using test-jars.

This however in my case would result in a cyclic dependency as follows:

- test - dependsOn -lib

  - src/main/java

    - MyMockObject implementsMyInterface
- lib - dependsOn: -test scope test

  - src/main/java

    - MyInterface
  - src/test/java

    - MyTest1 uses MyMockObject
- main dependsOn: -test scope test & -lib

  - src/test/java

    - MyTest2 - uses MyMockObject

How can I keep an organised structure for maven in this case?

Comment: I want some test utilities to be shared between tests in different modules.

Comment: In my opinion your idea is good and it is Maven drawback that scope-test dependecy is detected as cyclicdependency (there is no real cycle). As far as test-jar is fine you can keep it. If you decided to change you can split `lib` into `lib-api` and `lib-impl`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for Mavens recomandation not to use test-jar dependency is

> The downside of this solution is that you don't get the transitive test-scoped dependencies automatically. Maven only resolves the compile-time dependencies, so you'll have to add all the other required test-scoped dependencies by hand.

[source](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/examples/create-test-jar.html)

So if that is not a problem, just use a test-jar dependency.
You can also package only those test classes and resources into the test-jar that you really want to share  :

```
            <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test-jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <includes>
                        <!-- include only test resources from that package-->                               <include>**/com/prefabwarek/web/ui/page/include/*</include>
                        </includes>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: The quote is from https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/examples/create-test-jar.html